# SemanticImport fails with CSV when last column is ALL empty

Tags: import, csv-format

***(MMA v11.1.1)***

I have many empty fields in my CSV files and I couldn't understand why sometimes `SemanticImport` just failed to recognize the headers. I just find out that the problem is when **the last column is ALL empty**

Here is a minimal example:

*(for the purpose i use `SemanticImportString` with a string, instead of `SemanticImport` with a file, but the results are the same)*

```
SemanticImportString["a,b,c\n1,2,\n11,22,\n111,222,"]
```

> [image]

whereas if just one element exists in the last column, all works fine:

```
SemanticImportString["a,b,c\n1,2,\n11,22,33\n111,222,"]
```

> [image]

Trying to trick the process by specifying explicit delimiters like this produce an error:

```
SemanticImportString["a,b,c\n1,2,\n11,22,\n111,222,", Delimiters -> {",", ",\n"}]
```

[image]

The only **workaround** i found is adding an additionnal comma at the end of the lines:

```
SemanticImportString["a,b,c\n1,2,\n11,22,\n111,222," // 
  StringReplace[#, ",\n" -> ",,\n"] &]
```

> [image]

---

In comparison `Import` (or `ImportString`) works fine:

```
ImportString["a,b,c\n1,2,\n11,22,\n111,222,"]
```

> `{{"a", "b", "c"}, {1, 2, ""}, {11, 22, ""}, {111, 222, ""}}`

and `Export` (`ExportString`) of a table with an empty last column show that rows are just terminated with a comma, and that this format should be handled by mathematica:

```
ExportString[{{a, b, c}, {1, 2,}, {11, 22,}}, "CSV"] // InputForm
```

> `"a,b,c\n1,2,\n11,22,"`

---

So, I would say it is a bug ...

Any other workaround than adding (programmatically or manually) an additional comma to all the problematic files ?

Answer (score 2):

```
file = StringToStream["a,b,c\n1,2,\n11,22,\n111,222,"];
First@ImportString[#, "CSV"] & /@ ReadList[file, "String"]  // TableForm
Close[file];
```

[image]

edit: using `SemanticImport` on each line and making a dataset:

```
file = StringToStream["a,b,c\n1,2,\n11,22,\n111,222,"];
data = Normal@*SemanticImportString /@ ReadList[file, "String"];
{head, data} = Through@{First, Rest}@PadRight@data;
Close[file];
Dataset[Association[Rule @@@ Transpose[{head, #}]] & /@ data]
```

[image]

if you don't like zero fillers do this:

```
{head, data} = 
  Through@{First, Rest}@( 
    PadRight[#, Length@data[[1]], "empty"] & /@ data);
```

Comment: Thanks but at the end of my post I already gave a working example with `ImportString`, I know it works. Actually I do need the "Semantic" feature even if my minimal example do not show that, sorry if ithat was not clear.

Comment: you might take this and run `SemanticImportString` on each line as well.

Comment: The problem is that If I run `SemanticImportString` on each line separately, it does not produce a `Dataset` of the whole data.

Comment: oh i see, see edit

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with real data because `SemanticImport` needs to inspect a (whole?) column in order to infer what type of data it is. For example try with `"a,b,c\n1,9:00,\n11,10:00,\n111,11:00,"` where column b should be recognized as a time object. It is even worse if there is one element in the last column: `"a,b,c\n1,9:00,\n11,10:00,\n111,11:00,333"`

Comment: I just noticed this with some datasets we have here - the CSV files are written using some mythical python CSV library and each 'row' ends with a ,\n and not just \n. So I have a 'ghost column' without a label even. These Import OK but don't SemanticImport

Answer (score 1):

Here are two workarounds:

The first one is the one i gave already in the post and consists in adding an additional comma at the end of each line. This works but it probably should not and won't work when the problem is fixed:

```
file = StringToStream["a,b,c\n1,9:00,\n11,10:00,\n111,11:00,"];
Import[file, "Text"] // StringReplace[#, ",\n" -> ",,\n"] & // SemanticImportString
Close[file];
```

The second should be definitely more robust and consists in adding a given arbitrary text tag in the last column which will be explicitly recognized by `SemanticImport` as an empty field:

```
file = StringToStream["a,b,c\n1,9:00,\n11,10:00,\n111,11:00,"]; 
Import[file, "Text"] // 
StringReplace[#, ("," ~~ EndOfString | "\n") -> ",missing\n"] & // 
SemanticImportString[#,  MissingDataRules -> {"missing" -> Missing["Empty"]}] &
Close[file];
```

Both return:

> [image]

where the `b` column data type was correctly recognized as a time object.